# How to convert COPYDATASTRUCT's Data to a understandable string in VC++?

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

I am trying to change `poCopyData` (`PCOPYDATASTRUCT`) to a string and also a way to turn a string back into that. So i can send it, `poCopyData` is where the program copies the messages from another program to.

```
PCOPYDATASTRUCT poCopyData = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)ulParam;

// Note this is just outputs the message i don't how it converts it.
printf("Message (%u): %.*s\n", poCopyData->dwData, poCopyData->cbData, poCopyData->lpData);
```

Comment: Does [the example of this exact thing on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649009(VS.85).aspx) not sufficiently demonstrate what you need?

Comment: Ok i think that will convert it, do you know how to convert back into a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inline LRESULT CopyData( HWND hwnd, DWORD message, const char* str )
{
  COPYDATASTRUCT copy_data = { message, strlen( str ) + 1, str };
  return SendMessage( hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, reinterpret_cast< LPARAM >( &copy_data ) );
}

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam )
{
  if( message == WM_COPYDATA )
  {
    COPYDATASTRUCT* copy_data = reinterpret_cast< COPYDATASTRUCT* >( lparam );

    const char* str = reinterpret_cast< const char* >( copy_data.lpData );

    printf( "Message (%u): %.*s\n", copy_data->dwData, str );
}
```